# Can my father return to Canada after a refused entry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, denial-of-entry

My father travelled to Canada last month but he was refused entry at the airport and sent back.

The CBSA officers at the airport assumed that he would attempt to stay there because he took only 800 dollars with him, as he was to stay with a friend. When the officers called my father's friend to confirm everything, the friend did not know my father's full name.

He was not deported, but was given two options, to either appeal the decision, or to withdraw his application to enter Canada. He withdrew his application and returned home.

He still has a visa valid for 10 months. If he wants to go to Canada next month, will there be any problem

Will he be allowed to enter Canada this time? If yes, what kind of documents should he take with him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because he wasn't refused entry, he's free to try again.

He'll need better evidence of his ability to support himself.  I suspect the border officer's issue with your father's friend was that he didn't know your father well enough to know his complete name, which probably cast a doubt on the story.  If your father will be staying with someone else, get enough information together to make it clear why this makes sense, how they know each other, what the purpose of your father's visit is and why the friend is willing to help.  Because some people come to Canada to work illegally, customs officers expect the reasons to make sense.